# Why numpy.polynomial.laguerre.laggauss can not use more than 185 points for integration

Tags: python, numpy, integration

I am approximating an integral using Gauss-Laguerre quadraure using the function `numpy.polynomial.laguerre.laggauss` in python. I need to use a large number of points to have accurate results but it seems I can not enter deg>185 points and I have the following error.

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/polynomial/laguerre.py",
>   line 1726, in laggauss
>       w = 1/(fm * df)
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in true_divide

Is there a way to overcome this in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems now available:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 186

(root, omega) = np.polynomial.laguerre.laggauss(n)
```